Convert any TDateTime to UTC when Timezone is known
This seems as if it should be a no-brainer.
Here are the knowns.  I know the datetime of a "ticket".  I know its timezone because one of the properties of the Ticket is it's TimeZone as in
PST/PDT,EST/EDT,CST/CDT,MST/MDT
So I have TicketTime and Ticket Timezone.  TicketTime will not necessarily local to the computer that this code will run on so I can't use LocalTime.
Windows should know whether it is DST/ST for any given date.
My client asks that we return all times as UTC time.
With the above, it shoudl be childs play to make this happen.  But I can't get it figured out and I have not found an answer in here.
 uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils;

function ConvertToUTC(LocalDateTime: TDateTime; TimeZoneID: string): TDateTime;
var
  TZ: TTimeZone;
  UTCOffset: TTimeSpan;
begin
  // Get the time zone information
  if TimeZoneID = 'Local' then
    TZ := TTimeZone.Local
  else
    TZ := TTimeZone.Create(TimeZoneID);

  // Get the UTC offset for the given local datetime, considering DST
  UTCOffset := TZ.GetUTCOffset(LocalDateTime);
  
  // Adjust the local datetime to UTC
  Result := LocalDateTime - UTCOffset.TotalDays;
end;

procedure Test;
var
  LocalDateTime, UTCDateTime: TDateTime;
  TimeZoneID: string;
begin
  // Example local datetime
  LocalDateTime:= dtpLocal.DateTime; // DateTime of ticket
  
  // Specify the timezone ID (e.g., 'PST/PDT')
  TimeZoneID := 'PST/PDT';

  // Convert to UTC
  UTCDateTime := ConvertToUTC(LocalDateTime, TimeZoneID);
  
  // Output the result
  WriteLn('Local DateTime: ', DateTimeToStr(LocalDateTime));
  WriteLn('UTC DateTime: ', DateTimeToStr(UTCDateTime));
end;

begin
  Test;
end.

I found the above but it fails in multiple places.  I have looked at TimeZoneInformation but cannot see how to pass in the Timezone or offset.
What I thought was a 10 minute script is leaving me like a ball in high weeds.  Can I get a few lines to make this work?

Local<->UTC conversions are done in minutes, not days.  Since you have a TTimeZone, is there a reason why you are not simply using TTimeZone.ToUniversalTime()?

Abbreviations alone can't be trusted: CST could also be China Standard Time, PST could be Pitcairn Standard Time, CDT could be Cuba Daylight Time and so on...

I am only interested in CONUS.

It is simply
// Adjust the local datetime to UTC

  Result := LocalDateTime - UTCOffset;

=============================================
To elaborate a little and answer amigojacks comment:
TTimeSpan is a record which has a number of overloaded operators to allow you to interact with TDateTime records.
The particular one I am using here is
class operator subtract( const Left : TDateTime; Right : TTimeSpan ) : TDateTime;

That makes the syntax I have shown perfectly legal and meaningful.

So you think you can subtract TTimeSpan from TDateTime? Keep in mind that you posted an answer.

Absolutely I do @amigojack. TTimespan is a record with an overloaded operator that does exactly this!
